# My vb6 exe is crashing every time I try to print a document out of it

Tags: printing, vb6, erp

One of my client is facing this issue that the vb6 exe is crashing every time he tries to print the message text from the print button present in the exe.

Following is the code written for print button.

```
 iRetValue = GetProfileString("windows", "device", ",,,", strBuffer, 254)

strDefaultPrinterInfo = Left(strBuffer, InStr(strBuffer, Chr(0)) - 

tblDefaultPrinterInfo = Split(strDefaultPrinterInfo, ",")






Dim picount As Integer

picount = 0

    For Each objPrinter In Printers

        picount = picount + 1

        If objPrinter.DeviceName = tblDefaultPrinterInfo(0) Then

            ' Default printer found !

            Exit For

        End If

    Next


    If objPrinter.DeviceName <> tblDefaultPrinterInfo(0) Then

        Set objPrinter = Nothing

        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    Set GetDefaultPrinter = objPrinter

    txtPrintMsg.text = txtMsg.text

    txtPrintMsg.SelPrint objPrinter.hDC
```

Total printers they have are 700.

Comment: Asap is not a friendly word. Please tell us, on which line your code crashes.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What is the exact error message / form of the crash?

Comment: The very first line of code (with GetProfileString ) doesn't look like valid syntax

Comment: @nabuchodonossor -: My code crashes at last line.

Comment: @davelncaz :- while crashing it is not giving any  error messages and not even writing  error logs.It gets hanged for a while and closes itself automatically.

Comment: @Ryanchamania: Where is GetDefaultPrinter defined? Which type? Why do you think, txtPrintMsg.SelPrint does work? I can´t find this in VB6

Comment: @nabuchodonossor  Its a Public Function GetDefaultPrinter() As Printer and it was called on print button.This Code is working for all the other user but not for one.

Comment: @Ryanchamania: When it works for all users, did you already try to find the difference for the not working pc?

Comment: May be platform specific error!. Which is the operating system?

Comment: @Chandralal Windows 2007 64 bit..

Answer (score 0):

GetDefaultPrinter function return a bool value, while you try to SET a value.

Then, your statement: 
Set GetDefaultPrinter = objPrinter
is totally wrong.

GetDefaultPrinter function (Windows)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876(v=vs.85).aspx